# Trouble when using ApplicationUser: IdentityUser, UserManager in clean architecture asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, clean-architecture

I am working a asp.net core 6.0 WebAPI in a clean Architecture.https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture

There are 4 projects in this architecture.
WebApi, Infrastructure, Application and Domain.

- Domain is the Core.
- Application Layer is dependent on Domain Layer.
- Infrastructure Layer is dependent on Application Layer.
- WebApi Layer is dependent on Application Layer and Infrastructure Layer.

And The Queries and command (CQRS) should be written inside Application Layer

I want to use Asp.Net Core Identity.

ApplicationUser.cs  ( in Infrastructure/Identity )

```
namespace Infrastructure.Identity;

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
  // removed
}
```

IIdentityService.cs (in Application/Common/Interfaces)

```
namespace Application.Common.Interfaces;

public interface IIdentityService
{
    Task<string> GetUserNameAsync(string userId);

    Task<bool> IsInRoleAsync(string userId, string role);

    Task<bool> AuthorizeAsync(string userId, string policyName);

    Task<(Result Result, string UserId)> CreateUserAsync(string userName, string password);

    Task<Result> DeleteUserAsync(string userId);

   // and so on
}
```

IdentityService.cs ( in Infrastructure/Identity )

```
namespace Infrastructure.Identity;

public class IdentityService : IIdentityService
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public IdentityService(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager )
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

  //implementations of Interface by using userManager
}
```

above all work fine.

**My Issue is, I have to `UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager` to write a query (in APllication Layer )**

I got error, `Unnecessary using directive. [Application] The type or namespace name 'Infrastructure' does not exist in the namespace are you missing an assembly reference?) [Application]`

Query.cs  ( in  Application/SiteCodes/Queries/GetAll )

```
using Infrastructure.Identity;   // error

namespace Application.SiteCodes.Queries.GetAll
{
    public class GetAllQueryHandler : IRequest<List<SiteCode>>
    {

    }
    public class GetAllQueryHandlerHandler : IRequestHandler<GetAllQueryHandler,List<SiteCode>>
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;  // error
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

       // constructor removed 

       public async Task<List<SiteCode>> Handle(GetAllQueryHandler request, 
           CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var user = await 
           _userManager.GetUserAsync(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User);   // By using usermanger. I have to call more function like this from useManager

           // removed rest
        }
    }
}
```

**How can I do this without any error?. How can I call userManager and ApplicationUser ( : IdentyUser) inside Application Layer**

Please help me.

Note : I don't want to write function by myself like useManager package. I want to use userManager.

Eg: Like this

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

_userManager.GetUserAsync(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User);
```

Anyone have idea to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

In your application layer, you're only supposed to use the common interfaces. For example here, you shouldn't use the `UserManager` class directly, but use the public interface `IIdentityService`.

The application layer is described as:

> This layer defines interfaces that are implemented by outside layers. For example, if the application need to access a notification service, a new interface would be added to application and an implementation would be created within infrastructure.

That means you can extend the `IIdentityService` interface as needed, with the corresponding implementation in the infrastructure layer.

You also shouldn't be using the `IHttpContextAccessor` in your application layer, because it's part of the WebUI layer.

Some ideas to fix your issues:

- `IHttpContextAccessor` should only be accessed in the WebUI layer: in your API controller, get the current user from it, then retrieve the `ApplicationUser` and its ID from the `UserManager`
- pass the user's ID to your application layer
- use the `IIdentityService` with that user ID